# How to use breadcrumbs_on_rails in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, breadcrumbs

I try to use breadcrumbs_on_rails, but each time getting error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end add_breadcrumb "City", :doctors_city_sort_path(params[:city_id])
```

In controller:

```
def sort_by_city
  @doctors = Doctor.where('city_id = ?', params[:city_id]).
    paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page =>10)
  add_breadcrumb "City", :doctors_city_sort_path(params[:city_id])
  render 'index'
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
get '/doctors/city/:city_id', 
    to: 'doctors#sort_by_city', as: 'doctors_city_sort'
```

Please help to find decision for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the decision! It's look like:

```
 @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
 add_breadcrumb "#{@city.name}", "#{@city.id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a colon add_breadcrumb call, try this:

```
def sort_by_city
  @doctors = Doctor.where('city_id = ?', params[:city_id]).
    paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page =>10)
  add_breadcrumb "City", doctors_city_sort_path(params[:city_id])
  render 'index'
end
```

Comment: It's not working too :( I tried a lot of different variants, but anyone didn't work.